Wait for lambda image to be deployed before returning in aws cli
I want to update my lambda function with a new image by running
$ aws lambda update-function-code --function-name my-function --image-uri something

However the call to this command returns immediately. Is there a way to wait before returning until the new image is deployed?

You can use the CLI's wait command: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/wait/
